# Laravel multiple pivot relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot

I'm struggling with creating a relationship between two pivots that share single model.

The pivots in question are item_tag and playlist_tag. Below I have described the table and the relationships I have created already.

So i can currently get items for playlists, playlists for items, tags for items, tags for playlists.

What i'm struggling to do is :

- Get items that share the same tags as a given playlist
- Get playlists that share the same tags as a given item

I believe this may be done with a 'manyThrough' but honestly i'm lost.

---

Some more relationship detail

- Playlist can be comprised of many items
- Items can belong to many playlists
- So item_playlist pivot

---

Tags can be applied to both playlists and items

- An item can have many tags
- tags can be applied to many items
- so item_tag pivot

---

- A playlist can have many tags
- tags can be applied to many playlists
- so playlist_tag pivot

---

Example table structure

```
   Table : items
    id
    name

    Table : playlists
    id
    name

    Table : item_playlist
    item_id
    playlist_id

    Table : tags
    id
    name

    Table : item_tag
    item_id
    tag_id

    Table : playlist_tag
    playlist_id
    tag_id
```

---

Example class / relationship structure

```php
class Playlist extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
...
class Item extends Model
{
    public function playlists()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Playlist::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
...
class Tag extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function playlists()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Playlist::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the items that share *at least one* tag with a given playlist:

```php
$tags = $playlist->tags()->pluck('id');
$items = Item::whereHas('tags', function($query) use($tags) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $tags);
})->get();
```

Getting the items that share *all* the tags with a given playlist:

```php
$tags = $playlist->tags()->pluck('id');
$items = Item::whereHas('tags', function($query) use($tags) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $tags);
}, '=', $tags->count())->get();
```

The reverse direction works the same way.

Comment: ah, perhaps I was just over complicating it in my head. I was thinking there was an Eloquent way of achieving the same thing. Just going to wait and see if anyone has a different solution and will mark as correct.

Comment: staudenmeir, I tried this and it didn't work until i removed `'=', $tags->count()` what was that there for ?

Comment: `'=', $tags->count()` makes sure that an item shares *all* the tags with the playlist. Without this part, it selects items that share *at least one* tags with the playlist.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. I actually want to return items that have any of the tags. Would be great if you could update your answer with both and the explanation so when I accept it people know what's going on. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I assumed you are looking for complete matches. I updated my answer.